# Estimating a subpopulation's size based on distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, coupon-collector-problem

Say I have population $ n_1{} $, where each individual samples is unique and contains multiple traits. A subset of population$ n_1{} $ forms a population that I'm interested in, called $ n_2{} $. Each member of the population $ n_2{} $ contains a unique trait that is normally distributed. Is it possible to calculate the size of population $ n_2{} $ by evaluating the distribution of samples collected over time?